# Moving a Wordpress site to an EXISTING wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop already developped as a Wordpress site. My company has another website based also on WP to which they want to transfer that shop.

How can I move my shop based on WooCommerce to a different WordPress installation? We want the second WP website to incorporate that shop in a sub-domain.

Comment: you can used backupbuddy plugin here is the link 
http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only integration you plan to do is access to the e-commerce subdomain from the main site, then you don't need to move anything. Just create the subdomain on your DNS administration panel (Route53, Cloudflare, etc) point it to where the site is, then change the site URL in the table wp_options.

Your main site can remain untouched, except for incorporating links to the ecommerce one.

Comment: I solved my problem by deciding to create a separate wordpress instance and a separate databse, but your suggestion was helpful for future reference. Also - thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you its a official WP walkthrough for moving a site with or without domain and URL change. Be sure to backup your db. Hope it helps.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site

Answer (score 0):

You can export products and other information from old wordpress instance.

In the backend, Tools > Export > Wordpress. Choose products, posts and any other data you want to export.

On the new word press instance, you can import from Tools > Import. If you have Woocommerce installed in the new instance, the products will be imported with ease (along with images)

Hope this helps.